# Regex for LaTeX umlaut escapes?

Tags: java, regex, scala, latex

I am writing a Scala script which gets information from several sources, including a BibTeX file. Using the [jbibtex library](http://code.google.com/p/java-bibtex/) to parse the file.

My BibTeX source file contains LaTeX style escapes for non-ASCII letters, like

> author = {Fjeld, Morten and Sch\"{a}r, Sissel Guttormsen}

I tried to use simple replacement, but failed, because I cannot write a proper regex to match the escape.

The best I could come up with was

```
val stringWithEscapedUmlaut = """Sch\"{a}r"""
val properString = stringWithEscapedUmlaut.replaceAll("""\\"\{a}""", "ä")
```

but the regex engine complains about the match.

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 2
>   \"{a}

As far as I am aware, I should escape `\` and `{` in a regex, but not `"` or `}`. Nevertheless, I tried adding more escape backslashes at increasingly random places :( but no success.

Any ideas how to match this?

**Update** The solution for an A-Umlaut escape turns out to be simple (thank you Keppil for that). It is

```
replace("\"{a}", "ä")
```

But LaTeX also has escapes for other characters, for example `\{ss}` for `ß`.

Scala won't let me use "{ss}" in a string, so I tried using raw strings, """{ss}""". Then the whole replacement falls apart.

```
object Converter {

  def cleanLatexEscapes(rawString: String): String = {
    val aumlauts = rawString.replace("\"{a}", "ä")
    val oumlauts = aumlauts.replace("\"{o}", "ö")
    val uumlauts = oumlauts.replace("\"{u}", "ü")
    val scharfesEs = uumlauts.replace("""\{ss}""", "ß")

    return scharfesEs
  }  

}

import org.scalatest._

class ConverterSpec extends FlatSpec {
   "cleanLatexEscapes" should "clean 'Käseklöße in der Küche'" in {
    val escaped = """K\"{a}sekl\"{o}\{ss}e in der K\"{u}che"""
      val cleaned = Converter.cleanLatexEscapes(escaped)
      assert(cleaned === "Käseklöße in der Küche")
  } 
}
```

> cleanLatexEscapes
>   - should clean 'Käseklöße in der Küche' *** FAILED ***
>     "K[\äsekl\öße in der K]üche" did not equal "K[äseklöße in der K]üche"

What is happening here and how do I fix it so that both umlauts and scharfes es escapes are covered? Also, where do the square brackets come from in the test output?

Answer (score 2):

No need for regexes here, you can use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead of `replaceAll()`:

```
val author = "author = {Fjeld, Morten and Sch\"{a}r, Sissel Guttormsen}"
println(author.replace("\"{a}", "ä"))
```

If you really want to use `replaceAll()`, you need to escape both `{` and `}`:

```
val author = "author = {Fjeld, Morten and Sch\"{a}r, Sissel Guttormsen}"
println(author.replaceAll("\"\\{a\\}", "ä"))
```

**EDIT**

A literal `\` is escaped the same way as a `"`, i.e with another backslash. To clean all sequences you describe above, you could use:

```
val cleaned = escaped.replace("\"{a}", "ä").replace("\"{o}", "ö").replace("\"{u}", "ü").replace("\\{ss}", "ß");
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to remove the accepted mark because this doesn't work for all escapes, only for umlauts. Maybe you can extend the answer to cover it all? I posted more info in the question. I am still very new to Scala, and not sure exactly how the whole escape mechanism works.

Answer (score 1):

The replaces should read:

```
object Converter {

  def cleanLatexEscapes(rawString: String): String = {
    val aumlauts = rawString.replace("\\\"{a}", "ä")
    val oumlauts = aumlauts.replace("\\\"{o}", "ö")
    val uumlauts = oumlauts.replace("\\\"{u}", "ü")
    val scharfesEs = uumlauts.replace("\\{ss}", "ß")

    return scharfesEs
  }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JBibTeX library provides LaTeX parser (converts LaTeX string to a list of LaTeX commands) and LaTeX pretty printer (converts a list of LaTeX commands to a Java unicode string) classes. So, there's no need to mess with regex here.

The [README file](https://github.com/jbibtex/jbibtex) contains a working code example.